# How to return value from an async function in node js and save to a variable inside jenkins pipeline script?

Tags: node.js, jenkins-pipeline

Calling Node js script in Jenkins pipeline script as follows:
`def result = bat node abc/xyz.js`
`result.id` to be used later in the pipeline script

Inside `xyz.js`, I defined a function and returning value as follows:

```
function sampleFunc(){
    // func2 is an async function
    func2()
    .then(results) => {
       // below console stmt is able to print results
       console.log(results)
       return results
    })
}

console.log(sampleFunc())
```

console log prints undefined.

Comment: you already concluded that the `sampleFunc()` returns `undefined`, so the problem occurs inside that function. Without knowing the implementation helping will be quite difficult for us.... So please share it :-)

Comment: @n9iels Added more details now. No issue with func2 as results are retrieved properly. Looks like the issue is with how I return it

Comment: sampleFunc has no defined return value. If func2 is async then sampleFunc will immediately return.

Comment: @jeff Got it. How do I return the value of func2 ?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why `sampleFunc()` is returning `undefined` is that it is actually returning nothing. You are returning a value inside the `then` part of the async `func2()`. Since you are not returning `func2` itself, `sampleFunc` has no return value.

A correct implementation would be:

```
function sampleFunc(){
    // func2 is an async function
    return func2().then(results) => {
        // below console stmt is able to print results
        console.log(results)
        return results
    })
}

// func2 and thus sampleFunc are async. So the return value will be a promise and not the actual return value
sampleFunc().then(function(result) { console.log(result); })
```

Promises can be really confusing when you use them the first time. You can read more about promises here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

**Edit:** The example above will work if `func2()` has a correct Promise implementation and called its resolve function.

Comment: I am able to print the result inside sampleFunc() now. I added stmt `return results` inside sampleFunc(). However `def result = bat node abc/xyz.js` still returns null object

Answer (score 1):

Like n9iels said, you forgot to return a value. Another (slightly shorter) example below:

```js
function func2() {
  // Mimic async function
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve("Hello World!");
    }, 1000);
  });
}

func2().then(results => {
  console.log(results);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Node.js 8 or newer, you can use `async/await`:

```
function sampleFunc(){
    // func2 is an async function
    func2()
    .then(results) => {
       // below console stmt is able to print results
       console.log(results)
       return results
    })
}

async function main() {
    console.log(await sampleFunc())
}

main();
```